# Angular - Set and keep fixed parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to have a **fixed queryParameter in my url** that reflects the current application-instance. e.g. `...&instance=xyz`

- this parameter is automatically set
- it should be reset on every navigation (even if the user has removed it)

This is what i have so far in one of my components:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    let currentInstanceParam = this.router.routerState.root.queryParams['instance'];
    if (!currentInstanceParam){
        // always add current instance as parameter
        this.router.navigate([this.router.url], {queryParams: {instance: this.loginService.getLoginData().currentDataSource}});
    }

}
```

It works - if the parameter is not set already will be added.

But:

- If i click on a navigation-link that leads to the same component, the parameter simply get removed (it do not want to set `preserveQueryParams` for every navigation-link)
- Is there a more general way? (handle the fixed paramter in one place not in every component)